# ASP.net Core, redirect to Index method with error message from another method

Tags: asp.net-core

From this method I want to redirect to index method with error message.

```
ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty,"Item can't be deleted, item in use in expense.");
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Index method is SQL query with view model -

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var itemList = (from i in _context.Item
                           join ui in _context.UserItems
                           on i.ItemId equals ui.ItemId
                           //where i.ItemStatus.Equals(1)
                           where ui.userId.Contains(getLoggedInUserId())
                           select new ItemViewModel
                           {
                               Item = i
                           });
        return await Task.FromResult(View(itemList));
    }
```

RedirectToAction("Index") doesn't redirect with error message.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Core is by default stateless which means `ModelState` is not keeping the state between requests. So when you redirect from one controller action to another, you need to pass along the values together with the redirection request. One way to do this is using query parameters - also referred to as "route values" in ASP.NET Core:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { ErrorMessage = "Item can't be deleted, item in use in expense." });
```

Then your `Index` method needs to accept the `ErrorMessage` as a parameter:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string ErrorMessage)
{
    var itemList = (from i in _context.Item
                    join ui in _context.UserItems
                    on i.ItemId equals ui.ItemId
                    //where i.ItemStatus.Equals(1)
                    where ui.userId.Contains(getLoggedInUserId())
                    select new ItemViewModel
                    {
                        Item = i
                    });

    // Add the message to the ModelState if need be
    ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, ErrorMessage)

    return await Task.FromResult(View(itemList));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use TempData if the Index method doesn't accept any parameter:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Item can't be deleted, item in use in expense.";
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Index method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    if (TempData.ContainsKey("ErrorMessage"))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, TempData["ErrorMessage"].ToString());
    }
    var itemList = (from i in _context.Item
                    join ui in _context.UserItems
                    on i.ItemId equals ui.ItemId
                    //where i.ItemStatus.Equals(1)
                    where ui.userId.Contains(getLoggedInUserId())
                    select new ItemViewModel
                    {
                        Item = i
                    });
    return await Task.FromResult(View(itemList));
}
```

Comment: Nice, I never used `TempData`